# Storing duplicate keys in hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I am expecting duplicate key to be stored with value in `student_hash`, but due to absence of multimap in ruby, it is not allowed. One solution is to capture all this information in separate two arrays based on `selection(id/type/school_id)`, but input data might have so much depth, and array size cannot be determined. Can the same behavior (expected output) be achieved using a hash? Please suggest.

Expected output:

```
{:id=>"101", :type=>"junior", :school_id=>"IS1.4598"}
{:id=>"103", :type=>"Senior", :school_id=>"IS1.098"}
```

Code:

```
require 'json'

raw_data='{
  "Enquiry": "get_all_student_info",
  "success": true,
  "payload": [
    {
      "standard_version": "1.4",
      "country_id": "USA_01",
      "parent": "USA_IS1",
      "id": "101",
      "company": "Govt",
      "type": "Junior",
      "subsystem_type": "Govtgirlsschool",
      "school_id": "IS1.098"

    },
    {
      "standard_version": "1.4",
      "country_id": "NZ_01",
      "parent": "NZ_IS1",
      "id": "103",
      "company": "Private",
      "type": "Senior",
      "subsystem_type": "Govtboysschool",
      "school_id": "IS1.098"

    }
  ],
  "error": ""
}'

def student_hash(set, result = {})
  if set.class == Hash 
    set.each do |k, v|
      if("#{k}"=="id" || "#{k}"=="type"  || "#{k}"=="school_id")
        puts result ["#{k}".to_sym] = "#{v}"
      end
      if v.class == Hash
        result = student_hash(v, result)
      elsif v.class == Hash || v.class == Array
        result = student_hash(v, result) 
      end
    end
  elsif set.class == Array
    set.each do |a|
      result = student_hash(a, result)
    end
  end
  result
end

student_hash(JSON.parse(raw_data))
# => {:id=>"103", :type=>"Senior", :school_id=>"IS1.098"}
```

Comment: I don't really understand the objective - what do you want the output to be? would `{:id=>["101", "103", ...], :type=>"Senior", :school_id=>["IS1.4598", "IS1.098", ...]}` be okay? Are these the only fields you are looking for?

Comment: i want to set all this three values after reading into other function in the same order which I mentioned expected output. That's why I was looking for map option .

Answer (score 2):

Not to much clear but, This is enough to expected output for your `raw_data`

```
data = JSON.parse(raw_data)
data["payload"].map {|i| { :id => i["id"], type: i["type"], school_id: i["school_id"] }}
```

Now you can print hoe ever you want.

Comment: good answer jon , up vote for this . could you also let me  know if I can have check for  existence of all three types (id,type and school_id] similar to has_key  kind of property of has,

Answer (score 1):

Try with below function, it will give result what you are expecting.

```
def content_display( result = [] )
student_array = []
@array = []
result["payload"].map {|i|
student_array={ :id => i["id"], :type => i["type"], :school_id =>  i["subsystem_instance_id"] }
@array << student_array
}
 @array
end
array=content_display(JSON.parse(raw_data))
puts array
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you.

```
all_data = []

row = {:id=>"101", :type=>"junior", :school_id=>"IS1.4598"} 

all_data << row
```

For example

```
students = Student.all

all_student = []

students.each do |student|
  student_hash = {:id=>student.id, :type=>student.type, :school_id=>student.school_id}
  all_student << student_hash
end

puts all_student
```

You will get result something like that

```
[{:id=>"101", :type=>"junior", :school_id=>"IS1.4598"}
{:id=>"103", :type=>"Senior", :school_id=>"IS1.098"}]
```

Comment: What Student contains Here , I don't have any clue as I am looking similar solution .

Comment: I just gave you an idea, I hope if apply you it in row_data then it would work for you.